# Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Stream losing its parser

Tags: excel, perl

I have an 18M Excel spreadsheet to parse and `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` was consuming so much memory that it I had to switch to [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Stream](https://metacpan.org/module/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Stream). It works fine on my VM, it works fine on our staging server, but on our production server (configured the same way), I get this error:

```
Can't call method "transfer" on an undefined value at \
lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel/Stream/XLS.pm line 31.
```

That comes from the following bit of code:

```
my ($wb, $idx, $row, $col, $cell);
my $tmp = my $handler = sub {
  ($wb, $idx, $row, $col, $cell) = @_;
  $parser->transfer($main);  XXX here's where we die
};

my $tmp_p = $parser = Coro::State->new(sub {
  $xls->Parse($file);
  # Flag the generator that we're done
  undef $xls;
  # If we don't transfer back when done parsing,
  # it's an implicit program exit (oops!)
  $parser->transfer($main)
});
weaken($parser);
```

The `weaken` looked suspicious, so I tried not weakening unless the refcount was greater than 1, but the same problem happens. I instrumented the code to get a stacktrace and got this:

```
parser is undefined at lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel/Stream/XLS.pm line 29.

Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Stream::XLS::__ANON__                   \
  ('Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Workbook=HASH(0x6cd4a08)', 0, 2, 1, \
  'Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Cell=HASH(0x1387ce78)') called at    \
  /usr/share/perl5/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm line 2152
Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::_NewCell(                               \ 
  'Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Workbook=HASH(0x6cd4a08)', 2, 1,     \
  'Kind', 'PackedIdx', 'Val', 'Dean', 'FormatNo', 25, ...)       \
   called at /usr/share/perl5/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm line 896
Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::_subLabelSST(                           \
  'Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Workbook=HASH(0x6cd4a08)', 253, 10,  \
  '\x{2}\x{0}\x{1}\x{0}\x{19}\x{0}2\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}')             \
   called at /usr/share/perl5/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm line 292
Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::parse(                                  \
  'Spreadsheet::ParseExcel=HASH(0x6cd1810)', '2013-09-13.xls')   \
   called at lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel/Stream/XLS.pm line 35
Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Stream::XLS::__ANON__                   \
   called at new_importer.pl line 0
```

That tells me that the parser read the first and second rows, but it dies on the third row for some reason.

I've tried rebuilding `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Stream` and it doesn't appear to have any errors (all tests pass). I've also recompiled `Coro` (same result).

I'm mystified. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: have you tried to make $parser show a msg when it goes out of scope? i.e. $parser->{__debug_destroy} = DestroyNote->new().

Comment: can you reduce it to a self-contained runnable example?

Comment: The weaken is necessary because of the circular references in the anon subs and variables. You can see the memory leak if you comment out the weaken and then create S::PE::S objects in a loop. Assigning to $tmp_p makes sure the parser doesn't go away until it's supposed to.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem turned out to be rather strange and looked like this psuedo code:

```
stream1 = open first excel stream
sheet1  = stream1.sheet // get spreadsheet ready for reading

if in verbose mode:
    stream2 = open second excel stream
    sheet2  = stream2.sheet
    count++ while sheet2.get_row
    say "We have $count records"
```

We discovered that if and only if we were in verbose mode would this problem manifest. By having two streams pointing to the same document, our production code would fail, though this worked fine on other boxes. By counting the number of rows and closing that stream *before* opening the regular stream for reading the document, we solved the problem.

Comment: I was going to say that you couldn't parse two spreadsheets simultaneously, but I see that bug in S::PE was fixed (rt43250)

Comment: rt43250 does not address the problem I was thinking about. S::PE still can not simultaneously parse two or more spreadsheets when one or more of them use the CellHandler option (which S::PE::S uses).

Comment: Added a patch to rt43250 to fix this issue.

Comment: Is fixed as of v. 0.60. I'm the maintainer now, though not very actively recently.

Comment: And just to mention...normally this would not be a bug when just using S::PE since a spreadsheet gets fully parsed before parsing any other spreadsheet. This only manifests when using S::PE::S since it magically turns the cell handler callback inside-out into an iterator.